# Can't document enums

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to document an enum like this:

```
/**
 * Enum for the different types of tokens
 * @memberof Ecre
 * @enum {number}
 * @readonly
 */
Ecre.TokenTypes = Object.freeze({
    /**
     * A string token
     */
    "string": 1,
    "comment": 2,
    "number": 3,
    "boolean": 4,
    "identifier": 5
});
```

But this doesn't not work as excepted: `string` is being document as a global.

How can I achieve that the values are documented in a proper way?

I'm using JSDoc 3.3.0-alpha9 (Sat, 28 Jun 2014 15:26:03 GMT)

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty old question, but an answer still could be helpful. 
Since *Object.freeze* freezes the object, you can call it after enum is defined.

```
/**
 * Enum for the different types of tokens
 * @memberof Ecre
 * @enum {number}
 * @readonly
 */
Ecre.TokenTypes = {
    "string": 1,
    "comment": 2,
    "number": 3,
    "boolean": 4,
    "identifier": 5
};
Object.freeze(Ecre.TokenTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my code, and it works...

```
/**
 * Enum: Alignment values
 *
 * @property {Number} Bottom
 * @property {Number} BottomLeft
 * @property {Number} BottomRight
 * @property {Number} Center
 * @property {Number} Left
 * @property {Number} Right
 * @property {Number} Top
 * @property {Number} TopLeft
 * @property {Number} TopRight
 *
 * @enum {Number}
 * @readOnly
 * @memberOf gc
 */
var Align = Object.freeze({
    Bottom      : 0,
    BottomLeft  : 1,
    BottomRight : 2,
    Center      : 3,
    Left        : 4,
    Right       : 5,
    Top         : 6,
    TopLeft     : 7,
    TopRight    : 8
});

gc.Align = Align;
```

The problem is, that using `Object.freeze` the enum is not parsed automatically with jsdoc, but with a simple macro in your favorite text editor, the `@property` tags can be generated easily...

Not the best option, but at least the generated documentation is the same